# DB2 add Primary Key to existing table created from Jupyter Lab via SQL magic 'PERSIST'

Tags: python, sql, pandas, db2, jupyter-lab

I created sample table from Jupyter Lab notebook via:

```
file_csv = 'data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file_csv)
df.insert(0, 'KEY_ID', df.index)
```

Then added table to DB2 on IBM cloud via:

```
%sql PERSIST df
```

Looking at that table in DB2 console it is created w/o primary key - so I tried to remedy it:

```
ALTER TABLE DF
    ALTER COLUMN KEY_ID
    SET NOT NULL;
```

And set `KEY_ID` as primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE DF
    ADD PRIMARY KEY(KEY_ID);
```

But DB2 stubbornly refuses with following error:

> InternalError: (ibm_db_dbi.InternalError) ibm_db_dbi::InternalError: Exception('Statement Execute Failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0668N  Operation not allowed for reason code "7" on table "MYID9999.DF".    SQLSTATE=57016\r SQLCODE=-668')
>   [SQL: ALTER TABLE DF
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY(KEY_ID);]
>   (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/2j85)

Answer (score 1):

OK - I actually solved it while typing the question - but I will post it anyway. You need to REORG the table (I guess after resetting 'KEY_ID' column props to NOT NULL) and it only worked from when run like this:

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD ('REORG TABLE DF')
```

But after that ALTER command works like a charm.